# AD: Domain migration or renaming?

Tags: active-directory, domain, migration, rename

I've been given the task of listing down important activities with their estimated effort to help choose the best option/solution for the following scenario:

The current domain is named "Domain0" and users have logins like name@domain0.com

New users should have logins like name@domain.com and need to access the same resources in "Domain0".

In such a case, should a domain be renamed, migrated to a new one or redirected from "Domain0" to "Domain" (if that even makes sense). In the end, all that worked with "Domain0" should work with "Domain" so that "Domain0" can be completely deleted.

P.S. I'm a complete layman in this area, please excuse if you find this question absurd

Comment: how do new users have logins like name@domain.com already?  Is there a new domain setup or an alternate UPN already?

Comment: I mean new user "should" have logins like name@domain.com. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 5):

While there are tools that can rename a domain, it can be a complicated process.  You have a couple options.  1. You can add an alternate UPN so that @domain.com is valid.  2. You can migrate to a new domain.  I'd try the upn route first

Comment: Thanks @Jim B, UPN looks like a preferred option. Are there any cases in which this might not work? (Since you mentioned the word "try" in your answer)

Comment: An alternate upn will work for most applications but I've run across the odd app that (incorrectly) uses the implicit upn.

Answer (score 1):

Domain rename worked just fine using Microsoft's rendom.exe utility (I'd say it was easy, perhaps because there was no exchange server involved). Service logons were changed for SQL Services and everything worked smoothly.